# Django Best way to store price history of millions of products?

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql

I am running a web scraping spider that scrapes nearly 1 million products on a daily basis.
I am considering 2 approaches:
1) store all products prices history in one table

```
product_id, date, price
```

but this would yield a multi million records in this table.

2) store data in multiple tables & make separate table for each product.

```
Table1: product_id, current_price
Table_product_id: date, price
Table_product_id: date, price
Table_product_id: date, price
```

But I will have nearly 1 million tables!

Comment: Any reason why you would consider the second option?

Answer (score 2):

From the theoretical point of view, you should use the same schema to store instances of the same entity (e.g., your Product type). According to that, solution 1 should be preferred.

In the real world, high data cardinalities could be an issue. `MongoDB`, for example, use [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) for managing very large datasets. `PostgreSQL` allows [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-partitioning.html). From the PostgreSQL's doc:

> Partitioning refers to splitting what is logically one large table
>   into smaller physical pieces. Partitioning can provide several
>   benefits:
>
> - Query performance can be improved dramatically in certain situations,    particularly when most of the heavily accessed rows of
>     the table are    in a single partition or a small number of
>     partitions. The    partitioning substitutes for leading columns of
>     indexes, reducing    index size and making it more likely that the
>     heavily-used parts of    the indexes fit in memory.
> - When queries or updates access a large percentage of a single    partition, performance can be improved by taking advantage of
>     sequential scan of that partition instead of using an index and
>     random access reads scattered across the whole table.
> - Bulk loads and deletes can be accomplished by adding or removing    partitions, if that requirement is planned into the partitioning
>     design. ALTER TABLE NO INHERIT and DROP TABLE are both far faster
>     than a bulk operation. These commands also entirely avoid the VACUUM
>     overhead caused by a bulk DELETE.
> - Seldom-used data can be migrated to cheaper and slower storage media.
>
> The benefits will normally be worthwhile only when a table would
>   otherwise be very large. **The exact point at which a table will
>   benefit from partitioning depends on the application, although a rule
>   of thumb is that the size of the table should exceed the physical
>   memory of the database server.**

As they mentioned, it depends on you specific use case. The last sentence could be the criterion to make your choice.